# Implementing fast-forward with AVAssetReaderOutput

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch, avfoundation, gpuimage, avassetreader

I’m trying to add a fast-forward functionality in my app, which heavily uses GPUImage, but am running into some memory issues.

At the top of `-[GPUImageMovie readNextVideoFrameFromOutput:]`, I replace this:

```
CMSampleBufferRef sampleBufferRef = [videoTrackOutput copyNextSampleBuffer];
```

with this:

```
CMSampleBufferRef sampleBufferRef = [videoTrackOutput copyNextSampleBuffer];
if(GPUImageSpeedModeFast == self.speedMode) {
    sampleBufferRef = [videoTrackOutput copyNextSampleBuffer];
}
```

This seems to work for a few glorious seconds, but then my app is killed due to memory issues. I assume it’s the high rate of allocations, because there don’t appear to be any leaks. Anyone have experience with this? Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it seems as if the best route (for GPUImageMovie) is to just instantiate it with an AVPlayerItem, rather than trying to allow it to use its AVAsset path!